# How to query in django one to many

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-templates

## What I want to do?

I have an app have three models:`Series`,`Section` and `Episode`,every one have a one-many query(by ForeignKey). just like this

> series-> many Section,section-> many Episode

Now I will show a section with episodes information in series page, but it make more query.

### now code

views.py

```
series  = Series.objects.get(id=series_id)
section = Section.objects.filter(series=series)
```

list.html

```
{% for item in sections %}
...

{% for episode in item.episode_set.all %}
...
{% endfor %}

...
{%endfor%}
```

models.py

```
class Section(models.Model):
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
     ....
class Episode(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section)
```

### What I want to get ?

**an example code tell me how to query in views.py and use just little query.**

you can guess, in my code, if here are many section and many episode, it will have many query.

### Some idea.

I use Laravel Before, In Laravel , it has a [hasMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) Function, I can use it to get other models items(Define by [belongsTo](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)).
**Is Django has same function?**

Comment: Does your current views.py run? Do you have a template and, if so, what call are you using to send data to that template?

Comment: @ben i uss render to send data to template, but i think that not the key question. key question is get data in relation model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If in template you need only episodes, you can query just them with single query

```
Episode.objects.filter(section__series=series_id)
```

But if you need all data then you can use `prefetch_related` [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

The simplest example looks enough for your code

```
series = Series.objects.filter(id=series_id).prefetch_related('section_set', 'section_set__episode_set').get()
```

After this calls to `series.section_set.all()` and to `section.episode_set.all()` will not produce extra query.

Comment: yes, this is what i want . maybe i should learn how to use prefetch_related

Comment: Definitely, it's a powerful tool for increasing the queries' speed. And take a look at `Prefetch` object, you can pass it instead of string with field name to have much more flexibility (e.g. fetching only related instances that meet some condition)